# declare variables in a pl/sql block

Tags: sql, variables, plsql, declare

I am trying to follow this [guide](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-plsql.html) for creating `pl/sql` blocks and I am getting an ORA-00922:missing or invalid option on the `SET orderNumberSEQ...`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
declare
orderNumberSEQ number(5);
userid varchar(20);

begin
insert into bs_orders (userid, ono, timepurchased)
values('lilith', orderNum_seq.NEXTVAL,(SELECT current_timestamp FROM dual));

SET orderNumberSEQ := orderNum_seq.CURRVAL;

SELECT userid FROM bs_orders
where ono = orderNumberSEQ;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `SET`. Just

```
SELECT orderNum_seq.CURRVAL INTO orderNumberSEQ FROM DUAL;
```

will do the trick. Or if you use `oracle11`:

```
orderNumberSEQ := orderNum_seq.CURRVAL;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your initial approach.
While the selected answer correctly provides a way to determine the current value of the sequence is does not address these problems:

1. The value of the sequence might have changed between the call to NEXTVAL and CURRVAL. This will lead to a hard to detect bug and there is a possibility that you will get a value used by a different session. **Use the returning clause in the insert statement to retrieve the actual inserted value.**
2. Your variable names are the same as your column names. This will lead to hard to detect bugs in queries embedded inside PL/SQL blocks. **Make sure your variables are named differently - you can prefix them from the type name like v_userid instead of userid.**
3. SELECT statement inside an Oracle PL/SQL block requires an INTO clause. **Example:**

   SELECT userid INTO v_userid FROM bs_orders WHERE ono = orderNumberSEQ;
4. The sub-query for current_timestamp is redundant. **You can use plain CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in place of the sub-query to achieve the same result.**
5. Instead of manually providing the column type. **Anchor it to the exact table type using %type notation.**

   v_userid bs_orders.userid%type;

The following code addresses all 5 issues.

```
DECLARE
 v_userid bs_orders.userid%type; -- anchoring the type
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bs_orders(userid  , ono                 , timepurchased)
                 VALUES('lilith', orderNum_seq.NEXTVAL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  RETURNING userid INTO v_userid; -- instead of currval and an additional select
  -- do whatever you want with v_userid here
END;
/
```